# Creating functions with unspecified number of returns

Tags: python, pandas, return, definition

I have a simple code that takes three dataframes (Pandas library) and assigns values of the 'PROLIFIC_PID' column as the index of that dataframe

```
def pid_set(a, b, c): #accepts three dataframes at a time and returns dataframes with same name with PID as index
    a = a.set_index('PROLIFIC_PID')
    b = b.set_index('PROLIFIC_PID')
    c = c.set_index('PROLIFIC_PID')
    return a, b, c
```

I wanted to change the above code so that it takes X number of dataframes, sets PID as index, and returns X number of new dataframes. I tried multiple variations of the code above with no luck-- tried putting indexed dataframes in a list and return just the list, I have tried "pass" as the return etc-- but they do not function as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

You can just let X be a list of dataframes, like

```
X = [a, b, c, ...]

def pid_set(X):
    for i in range(len(X)):
        X[i] = X[i].set_index("PROLIFIC_PID")
    return X
```

And by the way, you don't have to return those dataframes, they will be updated even outside of the `pid_set` function.

Comment: I think something has to be returned. I tried creating a definition with a "pass" at the end and it did not set the index.

Comment: You can use this function and try to omit `return X` at the end, see if that does anything. Returning X is fine however.

Comment: Doesn't work man. I think we both need to review definitions more

Comment: When you tried to return the dfs as a list, why didn't that work? Can you post that code? and what are you doing with the list once the indices are reset? Sending back a list seems to be what you want (accept a list - return a list).

Comment: @TKim I too wonder how can this possibly not work. Post the entire code please. Also, did you try running the code with the `return X` statement? `newX = pid_set([a, b, c, ...])`